# Passed parameter not being converted from {{variable}}

Tags: angularjs

I have bunch of controllers for different routes and a factory to store some data needed in all of controllers.

```
.factory( 'global', function() {
    return {
        posts: null,
        selected_post: null,
        selectPost: function( post_id ) {
            console.log( 'test from factory: selecting post by id', post_id );
        }
    };
})
```

One of controllers

```
.controller('postsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'global', '$location', function($scope, $http, GLOBAL, $location ) {
    // ...  
    $scope.editPost = function( post_id ) {
        console.log( 'test from editPost', post_id );
        GLOBAL.selectPost( post_id );
        $location.path( '/posts/edit' );
    };
    // ...
}])
```

..calls a function from template inside `ng-repeat` passing post `id` to the factory like this

```
tr(ng-repeat='p in posts')
    td
        a.btn(ng-click="editPost('{{p.id}}')") Edit post
```

This, as I expected calls function, passing string like `id` to the `selectPost` function of the factory.

If I right-click at the button an open up inspector, I can see that the tag actually looks like this (`id` is a string, as I expected)

```
<a href="" ng-click="editPost('56c1b7b80712d1f307fbd842')" class="btn">edit</a>
```

The only problem is that in the console I get messages like:

```
test from editPost {{p.id}}
test from factory: selecting post by id {{p.id}}
```

So why despite the fact that inspector shows that function should have been called with string parameter of `id`, inside functions I see `{{p.id}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just give it to the function without converting it to a string like so, you will have the id as parameter in your function:

```
a.btn(ng-click="editPost(p.id)") Edit post
```

Answer (score 0):

> `a.btn(ng-click="editPost('{{p.id}}')") Edit post`

By writing that, you are setting parameter as string which contains literally "{{p.id}}".

Change it to:

```
a.btn(ng-click="editPost({{p.id}})") Edit post
```

Or just:

```
a.btn(ng-click="editPost(p.id)") Edit post
```